# The WTF behavior in class's dynamically allocated char array

Tags: c++, class, dynamic-memory-allocation

I crashed application every time I ran the code below. During debugging, I saw that the `str` object was self-destructing itself after the second line in `main()`. And it's quite a mystery for me. Try run it yourself:

```
#include<iostream>

class String {
private:
    char* string = nullptr;
    int length = 0;

public:
    String(const char str[]) {
        for (length; str[length] != '\0'; ++length);

        string = new char[length + 1]{};

        for (int i{}; i < length; ++i)
            string[i] = str[i];

        string[length] = '\0';
    }

    ~String() {
        delete[] string;
    }

    auto print() {
        for (int i{}; i < length; ++i)
            std::cout << string[i];
        std::cout << '\n';
        return *this;
    }

    auto getStrPtr() {
        return string;
    }
};

int main() {
    String str("123");
    auto strPtr{ str.print().getStrPtr() };
    strPtr[0] = '3';
}
```

Am I missing something?

Note on line 2 in `main()`: I am trying to print the `str`'s `string` array and then, since `print()` returns `*this`, I can chain methods and am calling a function that returns `string`'s pointer. But, even if in debugger it all executes perfectly, I have no idea why the hell `str` object deconstructs itself after.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: *Am I missing something?* -- A user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

`str` object is not destroyed on the second line of `main`. The temporary copy of `str` is destroyed.

Temporaries are destroyed at the end of full expression. This is normal.

---

Your class deletes a pointer member in destructor, but fails to maintain class invariant of uniqueness of that pointer. The behaviour of the program is undefined when the destructor of `str` deletes the same pointer value as the destructor of the temporary object deletes. Behaviour is undefined even before that when `strPtr[0] = '3';` indirects through the pointer that was deleted in the destructor.

Solution: Don't use owning bare pointers. Use smart pointer or container instead. `std::string` seems appropriate here.

---

> But why that temporary object was created in the first place?

Because you return a `String` object in `print`. You initialise it with `*this`, and therefore that object is a copy. You don't use the returned object to initialise a variable, so a temporary object is materialised.

Comment: And don't use `auto` everywhere for no good reason. It conceals bugs. Like how `print()` returns by value from a class that has broken copy semantics.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I don't think `auto` hides that here. The function returns `auto`, therefore it clearly returns by value. What it does hide is that the function returns `String` specifically rather than some other value type. Expecting `auto` to be a reference is less reasonable that expecting `String` to be a reference - outside of context - since latter could in theory be an alias of reference. That said, avoid type aliases for references except in cases where they are conventional.

Comment: Surely the OP intended to return a `String&`, and either didn't realise or didn't spot that their `auto` doesn't achieve that goal. We see it all the time. Sure, it's "clear", if you already know it and don't miss it!

Comment: But why that temporary object was created in the first place?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings `Sure, it's "clear", if you already know it and don't miss it!` So, the problem isn't that `auto` "hides" anything, but that OP is using something that they don't understand.

Comment: Of course it's not `auto`'s "fault", but it _does_ lull many people into a false sense of security due to its false appearance of simplicity.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings In my opinion, making programs appear unnecessarily complex is not worth it just to make beginners feel the complexity. There must be a better way to achieve that.

Comment: In my opinion, `String print()` shows the bug far more clearly. I don't think spelling a six-letter return type is particularly "complex". But your mileage may vary.